# UICollectionViewDataSource does not react on touch events

Tags: ios, xamarin, uicollectionviewdelegate

### Using Xamarin.iOS native in Visual Studio 2017.

I have my custom `UICollectionViewDelegate` with only overridden method `Scrolled()`. It serves me to scroll another `ScrollView` scrolling this one.
The initialization looks like:
`collectionView.Delegate = new MyCollectionViewDelegate(targetScrollView);`
But setting the custom delegate, my `collectionView.Source` stops reacting on touch events. `ShouldHighlightItem()`, `GetCell()` don't not fire. I can't interact with my `collectionView`'s content.

Does anybody know what should I do to force my `UICollectionViewSource` react on `ShouldHighlightItem()` and `GetCell()`? Should I override some method(s) in my `UICollectionViewDelegate`?

---

**Updated. The solution.**

I've found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate?language=objc) the methods I should to override in `UICollectionViewDelegate`: `ShouldHighlightItem()`, `ItemUnhighlighted()` and `ItemUnhighlighted()`.
I did not suspect that these methods' names are the same as in `UICollectionViewSource`. But I've overridden them and It's working well.

Comment: *UICollectionViewDataSource does not react on touch events* - that's good, because that's not a job for `UICollectionViewDataSource`. You need to implement the functions of `UICollectionViewDelegate`

Comment: I understand that. I want to say, that its methods `ShouldHighlightItem()` and `GetCell()` don't fire anymore, if I set custom `UICollectionViewDelegate` to my collection.

_You need to implement the functions of UICollectionViewDelegate_
- I don't know what exactly I need to implement.